# анонимные структуры и auto

Tags: c++

Всем привет, есть вот такой вот код. Скажите ,пжл, какого типа vt, и как авто его вообще вывел?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct
{
    struct
    {
      int t = 5;
    }Y;
}V;


int main()
{
    auto vt = V.Y;
    cout << vt.t << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Для начала можно попробовать хотя бы std::cout << typeid(vt).name() << std::endl; И выводится в таком случае, например, N4._82Ut_E

Comment: попробовал, консоль любезно выплюнула: N4._84Ut_E

Comment: Примерно такое и должно быть. Например, когда Вы тип лямбды определяете -- у нее НЕ тип функции, а там какой-то длинный код. Тут похожая ситуация, правда, я где-то встречал термин безымянные структуры, а не анонимные, уточните, как правильно.

Comment: да, тоже слыхал, что более правильно безымянные. Но qt creator при наведении на такую структуру называет ее анонимной. Мне вот очень интересно, а нельзя ли переменную vt определить не через авто, а ручками тип прописав?

Comment: можете написать decltype(V.Y)

Comment: хах, да, так можно, но как то не совсем ручками. Все равно за нас тип вывели.

Comment: груба говоря, хочу написать что то вроде V.Y vt = V.Y; заместо авто. Переменную типа function<...> я могу инициализировать лямбдой

Comment: @Slav9n92 Это не значит, что `function<...>` является типом лямбды. (Можно проверить через `std::is_same`.) Вам правильно пишут, что у лямбд (как и у вашей структуры) безымянные типы, и без `decltype`/`auto` их никак не получить.

Comment: До вас мне никто не написал, что по другому никак, были лишт предложения вывода типа. По поводу лямбды, конечно не значит, что тип один и тот же. но все таки инициализоровать я мог, да будут приведения типов но все же. Думал, что и со структурами так же можно извратиться. Раз нет, то  нет. Спасибо за ответ